# Coverity scan on travis matrix build

Tags: travis-ci, coverity

I am adding [coverity scan][1] to my project, but I'm facing problem with the quota limits because my travis build is using matrix.

I manage to run a custom coverity script (via *build_script_url* option) to filter my building job:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

if [[ $TRAVIS_OS_NAME != osx || $JOB != BUILD_RELEASE_JOKER ]]; then
  echo "Skip build configuration: $TRAVIS_OS_NAME / $JOB"
  exit 1
fi

curl -s https://scan.coverity.com/scripts/travisci_build_coverity_scan.sh | bash
```

I'm facing the problem that if the analysis quota exceed, it stop the build job with the following message:

```
Coverity Scan analysis selected for branch coverity.
Coverity Scan analysis NOT authorized until Fri, 08 Jan 2016 18:00:52 +0000 UTC.
```

The second bad side effect is that **the build job appears in green whereas the job hasn't been run**!

Answer (score 2):

what i've been doing for all my recent projects was, *optionally* (depending on the quota) running the coverity scan in my `before_script`:

```
before_script:
  - autoreconf -fiv
  - ./configure --disable-silent-rules
  # implement Coverity Scan with before_script instead of addons.coverity_scan
  # to work around too-early quota check by the coverity_scan addon
  - if [[ -n $COVERITY_SCAN_PROJECT_NAME ]] ; then curl -s 'https://scan.coverity.com/scripts/travisci_build_coverity_scan.sh' | bash || true ; fi

script:
- make
```

this will check whether i can still submit a new build to coverity, and if so, will run the `COVERITY_SCAN_BUILD_COMMAND` (which is just `make`). if this succeeds, it will run `make` again (in the `script`  stage), but due to the properties of *make* this will not do much.
if it fails (because the build fails), it will also run `make` again (in the `script` stage), which will soonish fail again, failing the entire build.

if however, my coverity quota is exhausted, the `travisci_build_coverity_scan.sh` script will fail, but this failure will then be turned into a pseudo-success via `|| true`.
then, in the `script` stage, the project will be build using `make`, and the final success depends on the outcome of this build.

so in short:

- if possible (due to quota), the build will be submitted to coverity
- if the build succeeds (with or without coverity), the travis-ci state will become *green* ("build passing")
- if the build fails (with or without coverity),  the travis-ci state will become *red* ("build failed")